# get a count of list item from listview

Tags: android, listview, fragment

i was trying to get a count of list item from listview but it didnt worked..

here is my code :

```
class Ambil_Buku_Keranjang extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //list item (2 item)
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            if (s != null && success == 1) {
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), daftarBukuKeranjang,
                        R.layout.list_keranjang, new String[]{TAG_KERANJANG, TAG_INVENTARIS, TAG_JUDUL},
                        new int[]{R.id.id_keranjang, R.id.kd_inventaris_keranjang, R.id.judul_buku_keranjang});
                listPesan.setAdapter(adapter);
                count = listPesan.getAdapter().getCount();
            }
        }
```

onActivityCreated :

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        new Ambil_Buku_Keranjang().execute();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),""+count,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

is there anything wrong in my code ? pls help thanks...

Comment: If you mean your `Toast` is showing the wrong count, it's because `Ambil_Buku_Keranjang` runs asynchronously. Move your `Toast` to `onPostExecute()`, or implement a callback interface for your `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @MikeM.  yeah thats worked..thanks

Comment: @MikeM. i have create a interface class but its doesnt worked..
inside asyncTask : public CountListItem jumlahList; and onPostExecute : jumlahList.setCountListItem(count);. and Log.d("QWERTYUIOP", ""+jumlahList.getCountListItem()); --> worked...and i try to call at onActivityCreated : Asy a = new Asy(); a.jumlahList = this; a.execute(); this.getCountListItem() --> result 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    if (s != null && success == 1) {
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), daftarBukuKeranjang,
                R.layout.list_keranjang, new String[]{TAG_KERANJANG, TAG_INVENTARIS, TAG_JUDUL},
                new int[]{R.id.id_keranjang, R.id.kd_inventaris_keranjang, R.id.judul_buku_keranjang});
        listPesan.setAdapter(adapter);
        count = listPesan.getAdapter().getCount();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),count,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

your task is asynchronous.

[Understand AsyncTask properly](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

you'll get the count in onPostExecute so you can not get count in onActivityCreated

Comment: you are welcome you can accept the answer to let others know, that is how you thank on StackO **Happy Coding**